# What is a more subtle way to express daring?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am working on a historical essay. I am trying to describe a person who is daring but more subtle than that. This person is always putting himself out there to try new things disconsidering the risks. He is an elegant person with some humor behind him. I am looking for a more subtle way to say this than daring in a single word.

Comment: Pushing the envelope.

Comment: Tell what he did to show that he is daring, and let the reader supply the adjectives.

Comment: @jejorda2 He didn't do anything "daring". Just things to put himself out in the world without considering much of the consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider 'insouciant' (adj.) or 'insouciance' (n.):

> **insouciant**, *adj.*
>   free from concern, worry, or anxiety; carefree; nonchalant.
>
> **insouciance**, *n.*
>   the quality of being insouciant; lack of care or concern.

[insouciant. (n.d.) Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary. (2010). Retrieved January 6 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/insouciant .]

An example:

> The Saint's *insouciance* vexed his opponents sorely.

Answer (score 1):

[**Adventurous**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjVlcqO8ZfKAhUBW44KHRe9Av4QFghpMAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.merriam-webster.com%2Fdictionary%2Fadventurous&usg=AFQjCNFLnP9RXduYBYAa0O6ZqumH78fFIw&sig2=rRGhvBG_-qjZrO0NRzMZQg), [**venturesome**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiz9-yp8ZfKAhXXxI4KHbQODHQQFgglMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.merriam-webster.com%2Fdictionary%2Fventuresome&usg=AFQjCNEXTpxW6hJAI1BXxXxWq_N96Sw87A&sig2=GwTzH8qhGR6cmdOwrLUB4A), or [**enterprising**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiVyOLI8ZfKAhXBto4KHRkWBKsQFghRMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.merriam-webster.com%2Fdictionary%2Fenterprising&usg=AFQjCNFb3PNEo89jM17B3Km-jHU07monGg&sig2=Etj7zmh2Y9l7SqXQHAQ0pA)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Adventurous? Brave? Or just explain/describe this person Without using the terms that label him as daring...if that make sense. It is more subtle this way, in my opinion.